# Need help retreiving the first occurence of something with beautiful soup and python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to search the SEC website to find the first occurence of "10-Q" or "10-K", and retreive the link found under the "Interactive Data Button" on the website.

The url that I am trying to retreive the link from is:

> https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=AAPL&type=&dateb=20200506&owner=exclude&count=40

The result link should be:

> https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=320193&accession_number=0000320193-20-000052&xbrl_type=v

the code I am currently using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

date1 = "20200506"
ticker = "AAPL"

URL = 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=' + ticker + '&type=&dateb=' + 
date1 + '&owner=exclude&count=40'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find(id='seriesDiv')

rows = results.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    document = row.find('td', string='10-Q')
    link = row.find('a', id="interactiveDataBtn")
    if None in (document, link):
        continue
    print(document.text)
    print(link['href'])
```

this code returns all the links of the 10-Q's, but it should be for both 10-Q and 10-K.

Can someone help me to mold this code so that it only returns the link of the first occurence of 10-Q or 10-K?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest solution is to use lambda in `.find()` method.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

date1 = "20200506"
ticker = "AAPL"

URL = 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=' + ticker + '&type=&dateb=' + date1 + '&owner=exclude&count=40'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find(id='seriesDiv')
rows = results.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    document = row.find(lambda t: t.name=='td' and ('10-Q' in t.text or '10-K' in t.text))
    link = row.find('a', id="interactiveDataBtn")
    if None in (document, link):
        continue
    print(document.text)
    print('https://www.sec.gov' + link['href'])
```

Prints both `10-Q` and `10-K` links:

```
10-Q
https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=320193&accession_number=0000320193-20-000052&xbrl_type=v
10-Q
https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=320193&accession_number=0000320193-20-000010&xbrl_type=v
10-K
https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=320193&accession_number=0000320193-19-000119&xbrl_type=v
10-Q
https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=320193&accession_number=0000320193-19-000076&xbrl_type=v
10-Q
https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=320193&accession_number=0000320193-19-000066&xbrl_type=v
```

---

EDIT: To get only first occurrence, you can use dictionary. Each iteration check if there's key (a string `10-Q` or `10-K`) inside the dictionary and if not, add it:

```
links = dict()
for row in rows:
    document = row.find(lambda t: t.name=='td' and ('10-Q' in t.text or '10-K' in t.text))
    link = row.find('a', id="interactiveDataBtn")
    if None in (document, link):
        continue
    if document.text not in links:
        links[document.text] = 'https://www.sec.gov' + link['href']

print(links)
```

Prints:

```
{'10-Q': 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=320193&accession_number=0000320193-20-000052&xbrl_type=v', 
 '10-K': 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=320193&accession_number=0000320193-19-000119&xbrl_type=v'}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This indeed filters for both 10-Q and K, that's awesome, thanks. Now, could you explain to me how I can retreive the link of only the first occurence? possibly parse in a list or something, but can't wrap my head around it

Comment: @Jackey12345 I updated my answer - you can use a dictionary to track the information that you found first occurrence of 10-Q/10-K.

Comment: Thank you so much this is great, it works like a charm!